# How do I set a custom culture before the page is rendered?

Tags: asp.net, globalization, culture

I have created a custom culture for client-specific language, i.e. I have resx files for that culture.
The issue I have is that I can't seem to set the culture early enough in the page cycle. By the time I call Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture and Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture the page seems to already have picked the language from the base resx file :(
So I'm having to set the culture and then redirect back to the same page?
I've tried setting it in the Page_PreInit and its still not early enough? Is there an earlier event I can hook into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the page's InitializeCulture() method, look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508(VS.80).aspx) for details.